# Undefined property pero el objeto si que existe

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente problema, mi PHP arroja el siguiente error:

> Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::$workbook

Este es mi código:

```
if ($this->primeraEjecucion) {
    $this->workbookName = 'nombre para el libro';
    $this->primeraEjecucion = false;
    $this->workbook = new Spreadsheet();
    $this->workbook->removeSheetByIndex(0);
}

foreach ($this->workbook->getSheetNames() as $s) {
    ...
}
```

ACLARACIONES:

- El error es en la linea del `foreach`
- La variable `$primeraEjecucion` se inicializa a `true`, y una vez pasado el if se poone como `false`, debido a que recorro varias veces esta función
- Si imprimo el resultado de `property_exists($this, 'workbook')` devuelve `true`
- Si imprimo el resultado de `isset($this->workbook)` también devuelve `true`
- Este es el valor de `$this->workbook` justo antes del `foreach` (dd en Laravel)
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

La notificacion se debe a que estas asignando un valor a una propiedad que no fue previamente definida en la clase.

### Solución

Solo necesitas declarar la propiedad en la clase

#### Ejemplo:

```
class HomeController {

    protected $workbook;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sí está definida, no lo puese en el OP porque pensé que se sobreentendía, fallo mío

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo en tu código esta removiendo las hojas con la linea:

```php
$this->workbook->removeSheetByIndex(0);
```

pudiera ser que al eliminar las hojas el método `$this->workbook->getSheetNames()` no tiene hojas y por eso te arroja el error, prueba comentando la linea.